# Convert either a hex string or a bytearray into an integer

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

Given an input which is either a hexadecimal string or a `bytearray`, I need to convert it into an integer.

Of course, one way to do it is to check on the type, for example:

```
a = '0xb8c2659029395bdf'
b = bytearray([0xb8,0xc2,0x65,0x90,0x29,0x39,0x5b,0xdf])

def func(x):
    if type(x) == str:
        return int(x,16)
    else:
        return int('0x'+''.join(['{:02x}'.format(i) for i in x]),16)

print(func(a))
print(func(b))
```

But I'm looking for a "neater" way.

One idea that I had in mind is to start by converting the input into one of the types.

For example:

```
def func(x):
    return int(str(x),16)
```

Or:

```
def func(x):
    return int('0x'+''.join(['{:02x}'.format(i) for i in bytearray(x)]),16)
```

But for the 1st option I get `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`.

And for the 2nd option I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16`.

Any idea how to resolve this issue, or to solve the original problem in a different manner?

Comment: `bytearray.fromhex("xxxxxx")` ?

Answer (score 1):

"Neater" isn't always better. It's a waste to turn a bytearray into a string only to then turn the string into an integer, when you can directly turn a bytearray into an integer.

eg.

```
def func(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return int(x, base=16)
    else:
        assert isinstance(x, (bytearray, bytes))
        return int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big')

assert func(bytearray(b'\xff\x00')) == func('0xff00') == 0xff00
```

Comment: I agree, but performance is not an issue in my case, so I'd rather neater in terms of coding.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Code should be simple, documented, terse and in that order. Performance is a separate consideration that takes precedence over all three, but only when performance is critical. I gave my answer because it is simpler than your bytearray conversion, not because it is performant. The only reason I would not write this function this way is if I was doing a code golf challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.hex) method of the bytearray to convert the bytearray to a string that you can parse:

```
def func(x):
    if hasattr(x, 'hex')
        x = x.hex()
    return int(x,16)
```

For example:

```
>>> func('0xffff')
65535
>>> func(bytearray([0xff, 0xff])) 
65535
```

Comment: Well, you've used an `if` so what benefit does that have over my method?